# Declaring variables inside a function python

Tags: python-3.x, function, variables

For some reason I keep getting error in my code stating that my variables have not been declared. This only happens when I try to declare them in a function and not outside.

example

```
x, y = 105,107 
print (x,y)
```

the above line of code works and gives me the output 105 107

but when I do this below

```
def fun1():
  x, y = 105,107 
print (x,y)
```

I get NameError: name 'x' is not defined

need help to understand what's happening.

Comment: Well, `x` and `y` were defined inside the function, so they're local to this function and not accessible anywhere outside it. See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the main utilities of functions is exactly the way they allow one
to isolate variables - no worries about clashing names for the code
in various functions - once a function works properly, it is done.

But if one **needs** to expose variables that populated inside functions to
the outside world, it is possible with the keyword "global". Notice that this
is in general considered bad practice, and even for small scripts,
there are often better solutions. But, common sense should always be the rule:

```
def fun1():
   global x, y
   x, y = 105, 107

fun1()
print(x, y)
```

Note that your code had another incorrect assumption: code
inside function bodies is not executed unless the function is called -
so, in the example in your question, even if you had declared
the variables as global, the `print` call would still
raise the same error, since you are not executing the line
that defines these variables by calling the function.

Now, you've learned about "globals" - next step is forget it
exists and learn how to work with variables properly encapsulated
inside functions, and when you get to some intermediate/advanced
level, then you will be able to judge when "globals" might actually
do more good than harm (which is almost never).